# Singularity container: can we make a container out of an environment from within this environment?

Tags: singularity-container

I have an ambitious demand.

I am connected to a distant server through SSH, and I have a conda environment installed on it.

Is it possible using Singularity to create a container that "copy" this distant server and the conda env that goes with it ?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to copy a folder (in this case, a conda env) into your singularity container.

You can leverage the `%setup` section if you have ssh keys set up with this remote host. Reference for `%setup`: https://apptainer.org/docs/user/main/definition_files.html#sections

Something like the following:

```
%setup
  scp remote_user@remote_host:/full/path/to/remote/conda/env ${APPTAINER_ROOTFS}/full/path/to/container/conda/env
```

Alternatively, you could create a tmpdir on your local system and scp the file into the tmpdir within `%setup` then use the `%files` to copy the files over to the container.

Comment: It's probably better to fetch the files before building. Commands in `%setup` are run on the host OS. Since `singularity build` generally requires root/sudo privileges, this also means that the command will be run as root and not the current user. This can have unforeseen consequences and could also cause the scp command to fail for a non-obvious reason.